# Problems with robot modeling in model.sdf

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am somewhat new to Gazebo

I have modelled a biped humanoid about 5+ feet tall in standard sdf format required for gazebo.
The robot consists of simple boxes for links for collision/visual and I have assigned the joints so i can connect these links together.

There are no errors with the model nor the actual XML description. however, i have the following issues. There is no way to set the joints so they are stiff (especially at the hips and knees level). When i let the robot stand it collapses to the ground shortly after due to wobbling.

i have set "effort" "friction" "damping' values to keep the robot from collapsing but its been useless.

I have seen the DRC robot's model.sdf but there's is it does not help.

Is there a way to keep the robot from collapsing?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51436/problems-with-robot-modeling-in-model.sdf/) by [nordegren](https://answers.ros.org/users/3894/nordegren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the joints of your robot do not have controllers that apply torques/efforts to them. You could write your own plugin for applying such forces (see [this gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/control_robot/mobile_base)).
A simpler option is the use of existing controller plugins, similar to how it is done on the drc robot. That model is a URDF model however, so I am not totally sure you can apply things to your pure SDF.
The simplest option is to use per joint position PID controllers as it is done in the [atlas_position_controllers.launch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/819a60eb91646f9bed3fa1c414553cf4753e4cff/ros/atlas_utils/launch/atlas_position_controllers.launch?at=default) launch file. This gives you one '/[joint_controller_name]/command' topic per joint that listens to std_msgs/Float64 position commands.
Another option is the use of of whole body trajectory action controller as it is currently done in the default atlas.launch file, which in turn includes [atlas_bringup.launch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/819a60eb9164/ros/atlas_utils/launch/atlas_bringup.launch?at=default).

It's recommended you have a look at the [drcsim tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/), those show some basics of how a robot like yours can be controlled (no fancy walking or whole body control available though, all drc teams are busy working on that ;) ).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0